Welch-Satterthwaite degrees of freedom (combining rule for indirect comparison)
In Network Analysis, an indirect comparison of the mean difference between treatment "A" and "B" from different studies over a common reference treatment "C" is made by:
$$
indirect MD(AvsB) = direct MD(AvsC) - direct MD(BvsC)
$$
where MD = Mean Difference
A 95% confidence interval for the indirect summary effect is constructed by the formula:
$$
[indirect MD(AvsB) ± 1.96 \sqrt{(Variance[indirectMD(AvsB)])}]
$$
where
$$
Variance[indirectMD(AvsB)] = Variance[directMD(AvsC)] + Variance[directMD(BvsC)]
$$
Question: Now, if we want to apply the Welch-Satterthwaite correction and the t-distribution to cosnstruct confidence intervals for a balanced case (equal sample sizes), whats the combining rule for the variances and degrees of freedom (df)?
Degrees of freedom:
$$
\frac{(variance_{AvsC} + variance_{BvsC})^2}{\left(\frac{(variance_{AvsC})^2}{n_{C} - 1}\right) + \left(\frac{(variance_{BvsC})^2}{n_{C} - 1}\right)}
$$
where
$$
variance_{AvsC} = \frac{sd_A^2}{n_A} + \frac{sd_{\text{c}}^2}{n_{\text{c}}}
$$
and
$$
variance_{BvsC} = \frac{sd_B^2}{n_B} + \frac{sd_{\text{c}}^2}{n_{\text{c}}}
$$
couldn't find any source...

You would have two different $\text{sd}_c$ and $n_c$ values from two independent studies, not the same ones twice, right? Or are the $C$ values the same for both these studies?

@Glen_b Although they are two different studies, the control is the same in that specific example above. Thanks for the advice, as I didn't denote the control as C1​ for Study 1 and C2​ for Study 2 to account for the general case.

Okay, if it's the same one you don't want to treat it as two different ones. Wait ... both studies are comparing a treatment to a control from ... yet another study?

@Glen_b, thank you very much for your conclusive explanations. One last remark: both studies compared the treatment to a control within the same study, but this control is the same in both studies (for clarification, the example referred to a lab study where the experiments were conducted consecutively and therefore published in two separate papers). The direct comparison AvsB is considered invalid by some authors, although in this particular case it seems valid to me as well (as you demonstrated mathematically)

It's not clear to me what argument would yield the conclusion that you can compare both A and B to C but not to each other. e.g. if the argument was that the conditions might subtly differ between A and B due to them being conducted consecutively,  that argument would also apply to at least one of the comparisons involving C.

Because its the same control both times, its variance disappears from the difference (its correlation with itself is 1, not 0, and the contribution of the covariance of the difference cancels the C variance terms). I presume your intent was to assume that the A's, B's and C's are mutually independent. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_A - \bar{X}_B) &=& \operatorname{Var}((\bar{X}_A-\bar{X}_C) - (\bar{X}_B-\bar{X}_C)) \\
 &=& \operatorname{Var}((\bar{X}_A-\bar{X}_B) - (\bar{X}_C-\bar{X}_C)) \\
 &=& \operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_A) + \operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_B) + 
  \operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_C-\bar{X}_C) \\
 &=& \operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_A) + \operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_B)
\end{eqnarray}
So you would ignore the C's and just add the variance terms for A and B, computing df in the usual way for a two sample Welch test, assuming you have $s_A^2, s_B^2, n_A$ and $n_B$.
If you instead had two different controls, and wanted to subtract the B-D difference from the A-C difference then it would be slightly more complicated. With both controls (say C and D) being independent of each other and the two treatments, to get the variance of the A-C difference minus the B-D difference, you'd add all the estimates of variances of the means (i.e. $\sum_i s_i^2/n_i$ for $i \in {A,B,C,D}$), and the approximate df would be
$$\frac{\sum_i \frac{s_i^2}{n_i}}{\sum_i \frac{s_i^4}{n_i^2 \nu_i}}$$ simply by noting that when the components (the $X_i$s) are independent, $\operatorname{Var}(\sum_i k_i X_i) = \operatorname{Var}(\sum_i |k_i| X_i)$ and then using the degrees of freedom formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation
(Or you should also be able to get it by applying the two-sample formula repeatedly to AvC then BvD and then treating both of those as two new variates to which you apply the two sample formula.)
Of course for such a calculation to amount to a comparison of A and B means you'd have to assume the C and D population means were equal. It would be better (assuming the information is available) to compare the A and B values directly; the variance of the difference should be considerably smaller.

That's reasonable given the question, but I am fairly confident it's wrong for what was intended.  The network meta-analysis setup is that you have some experiments comparing A to B and some comparing B to C. So while both comparisons use the same control treatment, they use different control participants and the uncertainty in B doesn't cancel out.   For why I think I know better than the question here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12210616/

Thanks Thomas  ...even with the question's notation suggesting otherwise  this kind of possibility was why I was asking clarifying  questions under the post... but was led no closer to a correct understanding. I'll take a look at your link when I can and see how I might best address  it

@ThomasLumley Thanks for the advice. The "Bucher method" mentioned clearly falls short for detecting inconsistency and incoherence. Setting aside mixed model assumptions, two studies (A vs. C and B vs. C) based on summary statistics don't provide enough data to improve on the indirect comparison A vs B. If the control in both studies has the same summary statistics, no variability is introduced by it, which questions the need to include it in the calculation, as Glen pointed out. However, wider cofidence intervals by keeping the control could indicate potential variability.

The derivation in my answer relies on the $\bar{X}C$ being the same random variable in both comparisons (I assumed that "C" related to the same random variable). If they're the same, then the correlation is (clearly) 1 and the terms cancel. But if they're not the same variable (if we had $\bar{X}{C_1}$ and $\bar{X}_{C_2}$, say, for two distinct subsamples of the controls), and the sample mean and variance just came out the same by chance (as unlikely as that would be), then the correlation would not be 1, and the terms would not cancel. I've done two possible cases, not the general case

If there was some dependence within-control samples that was neither perfectly correlated nor independent then neither case I discussed suffices.

The Welch-Satterwaite approximation uses the method-of-moments
The Welch-Satterwaite approximation is used to approximate a linear combination of scaled chi-squared random variables by a single scaled chi-squared random variable.  The goal is to approximate a random variable of the form:
$$S_*^2 \equiv \sum_i k_i S_i^2
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\frac{S_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} \sim \frac{\text{ChiSq}(v_i)}{v_i},$$
which has the true distribution:
$$S_*^2 \sim \sum_i k_i \sigma_i^2 \cdot \frac{\text{ChiSq}(v_i)}{v_i}.$$
To approximate this distribution we use the following distributional form:
$$\sigma_*^2 \equiv \sum_i k_i \sigma_i^2
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad 
\frac{S_*^2}{\sigma_*^2} \sim \frac{\text{ChiSq}(v_*)}{v_*}.$$
It then remains to determine the appropriate degrees-of-freedom $v_*$ for the approximation.  The Welch-Satterwaite approximation uses the method of moments by equating the first two moments (mean and variance) under the true distribution and the approximating distribution.  Under the true distribution, we obtain the first two moments:$^\dagger$
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(S_*^2)
&= \mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_i k_i S_i^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_i k_i \mathbb{E}(S_i^2) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_i k_i \sigma_i^2 \\[6pt]
&= \sigma_*^2, \\[14pt]
\mathbb{E}(S_*^4)
&= \mathbb{E} \bigg( \bigg( \sum_i k_i S_i^2 \bigg)^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E} \bigg( \sum_i \sum_j k_i k_j S_i^2 S_j^2 \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_i \sum_j k_i k_j \mathbb{E}(S_i^2 S_j^2) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_i k_i^2 \mathbb{E}(S_i^4)  + \sum_{i \neq j} k_i k_j \mathbb{E}(S_i^2) \mathbb{E}(S_j^2) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_i k_i^2 \sigma_i^4 \bigg( 1+\frac{2}{v_i} \bigg) + \sum_{i \neq j} k_i k_j \sigma_i^2 \sigma_j^2 \\[6pt]
&= 2 \sum_i \frac{k_i^2 \sigma_i^4}{v_i} + \sum_i \sum_j k_i k_j \sigma_i^2 \sigma_j^2 \\[6pt]
&= 2 \sum_i \frac{k_i^2 \sigma_i^4}{v_i} + \bigg( \sum_i k_i \sigma_i^2 \bigg)^2 \\[6pt]
&= 2 \sum_i \frac{k_i^2 \sigma_i^4}{v_i} + \sigma_*^4, \\[14pt]
\mathbb{V}(S_*^2)
&= \mathbb{E}(S_*^4) - \mathbb{E}(S_*^2)^2 \\[12pt]
&= 2 \sum_i k_i^2 \sigma_i^4/v_i. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
Under the approximating distribution we obtain the mean $\mathbb{E}(S_*^2) = \sigma_*^2$ and the variance $\mathbb{V}(S_*^2) = 2\sigma_*^4/v_*$.  By construction we have already formed the approximation to match the means.  Equating the variances of the true distribution and the approximation then gives:
$$v_* = \frac{\sigma_*^4}{\sum_i k_i^2 \sigma_i^4/v_i} = \frac{(\sum_i k_i \sigma_i^2)^2}{\sum_i k_i^2 \sigma_i^4/v_i}.$$
This gives the degrees-of-freedom parameter that would equate the variance of the approximating distribution with the variance of the true distribution.  Since this depends on the true variance parameters, we use an estimator for this quantity, giving the degrees-of-freedom:
$$\hat{v}_* = \frac{(\sum_i k_i S_i^2)^2}{\sum_i k_i^2 S_i^4/v_i}.$$

$^\dagger$ This working uses the second moment of the chi-squared distribution.   We have:
$$\mathbb{E}(S_i^4) = \sigma_i^4 \cdot \frac{v_i(v_i+2)}{v_i^2} = \sigma_i^4 \cdot \frac{v_i+2}{v_i} = \sigma_i^4 \bigg( 1+\frac{2}{v_i} \bigg).$$
